# Regular expression special characters not working at the starting of the string in java

Tags: java, regex

After trying other variations, I use this regular expression in Java to validate a password:

```
PatternCompiler compiler = new Perl5Compiler();
PatternMatcher matcher = new Perl5Matcher();
pattern = compiler.compile("^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?![\\\\\\\\_\-])(?=.*?[0-9])([A-Za-z0-9-/-~]
[^\\\\\\\\_\-]*)$");
```

But it still doesn't match my test cases as expected:

`Apr@2017`    match
`$$Apr@2017`  no match, but it should match
`!!Apr@2017`  no match, but it should match
`!#ap#2017`   no match, but it should match
`-Apr@2017`   it should not match
`_Apr@2017`   it should not match
`\Apr@2017`   it should not match

Except three special characters `-` `_` `\` remaining, all should match at the start of the string.

**Rules:**

- It should accept all special characters any number of times except above three symbols.
- It must and should contain one number and Capital letter at any place in the string.

Comment: Well, please try [`^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])[^\\\\_-].*$`](https://regex101.com/r/cmut9v/3). Please provide the rules in the question.

Comment: Could you please give expression same as mine by including the special characters at the starting of the string . Whole expression change is not a good practice which is in production environment

Comment: Replace `[A-Za-z0-9-/-~]` with `(?:[A-Za-z0-9-/-~]|[^\\w\\\\-])` then. But `[^\\\\\\\\_\-]` looks too convoluted, it must be `[^\\\\_-]`. And please be aware that `/-~` matches more than just 3 symbols as it is a *range* from `/` to `~`.

Comment: How can `!#ap#2017` match when there's no capital letter?

Comment: And in your regex the `[A-Za-z0-9-/-~]` suggest that the starting character should be limited. So, as @WiktorStribiżew pointed out, `/-~` is a range matching basically every ASCII character - what's your intention?

Answer (score 1):

You have two rules, why not create more than one regular expression?

> It should accept all special characters any number of times except above three symbols.

For this one, make sure it **does not** match `[-\\_]` (note that the `-` is the first character in the character class or it will be interpreted as a range.

> It must and should contain one number and Capital letter at any place in the string.

For this one, make sure it matches `[A-Z]` and `[0-9]`

To make it easy to modify and extend, do some abstraction:

```
class PasswordRule
{
    private Pattern pattern;
    // If true, string must match, if false string must not match
    private boolean shouldMatch;

    PasswordRule(String patternString, boolean shouldMatch)
    {
        this.shouldMatch = shouldMatch;
        this.pattern = compiler.compile(patternString);
    }

    boolean match(String passwordString)
    {
        return pattern.matches(passwordString) == shouldMatch;
    }
}
```

I don't know or care if I have the API to Perl5 matching correct in the above, but you should get the idea. Then your rules go in an array

```
PasswordRule rules[] = 
{
    PasswordRule("[-\\\\_]", false),
    PasswordRule("[A-Z]", true),
    PasswordRule("[0-9]", true)
};

boolean passwordIsOk(String password)
{
    for (PasswordRule rule : rules)
    {
        if (!rule.match(password) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Using the above, your rules are far more flexible and modifiable than one monstrous regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need

```
"^(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])[^\\\\_-]*$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cmut9v/4)

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])` - a positive lookahead that requires at least 1 ASCII letter (`[a-zA-Z]`) to appear after 0+ chars other than letters (`[^a-zA-Z]*`)
- `(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])`- at least 1 ASCII digit (same [principle of contrast](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast) as above is used here)
- `[^\\\\_-]*` - 0+ chars other than `\` (inside a Java string literal, `\` should be doubled to denote 1 literal backslash, and to match a single backslash with a regex, we need double literal backslash), `_`, `-`
- `$` - end of string (`\\z` might be better though as it matches at the *very* end of the string).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution - reverse the condition. This regex

```
^(?:[^0-9]*|[^A-Z]*|[_\\-].*)$
```

matches **non** conforming passwords. This makes it much simpler to understand.

It matches either

- a string free from digits
- a string free from capital letters
- a string containing either of `_`, `\` or `-`

[See it illustrated here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iQIRAX/2).

There are some unclear issues remaining in your question though, so it may have to be adjusted. (The restriction in starting character I mentioned as a comment)